# How to create a skin for fl.controls.Slider with custom height in actionscript only?

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs5, skin

I created a skin called customSliderTrack in the graphical editor of Adobe Flash CS5.5. This Slider is now in the "library" of the FLA file.

I can apply this skin with the following code:

```
var cls:Class = getDefinitionByName("CustomSliderTrack") as Class;
var tmpTrack:Sprite = new cls();
slider.setStyle("sliderTrackSkin",tmpTrack);
```

However due to the binary nature of the FLA file and lack of compatibility of different Versions of Adobe Flash I need to implement it all in Actionscript.

I understand that cls is a MovieClip object but I cant get the same results with `new MovieClip()`. I think this might be related to the dashed Lines in the graphical editor(I modified the default SliderTrack_skin). I havn't found out yet what they mean and how to replace them with Actionscript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setStyle` automatically sets the `track.height` and `track.width`. In case of the `track.height` the `slider.height` attribute does not seem to have any effect. To work around this problem simply set the `track.height` to the best value.

To access the `track` extend the Slider class and override the `configUI` Function:

```
public class CustomSlider extends Slider
{
    override protected function configUI():void
    {
        // Call configUI of Slider
        super.configUI();
        // The sprite that will contain the track
        var t:Sprite = new Sprite();
        // Draw the content into the sprite
        t.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 0.1);
        t.graphics.drawRect(0, -15, width, 30);
        t.graphics.endFill();
        // Set the Sprite to be the one used by the Slider
        this.setStyle("sliderTrackSkin",t);
        // Reset the height to the value that it should be
        track.height = 30;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of your track asset, you could accomplish this with the drawing API: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html

A very simple example would be:

```
var track:Sprite = new Sprite();
track.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xcccccc);
track.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 1);
track.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 20);
track.graphics.endFill();
track.scale9Grid = new Rectangle(2, 2, 396, 16);
slider.setStyle("sliderTrackSkin",track);
```

This creates a track that is just a black rectangle, 400x20 pixels in size. You can set the [scale9grid](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scale9Grid) in code to control how the skin scales. In the example above the rectangle's border wont scale, but the black rectangle inside will. Experimenting with the methods in the drawing API could be all you need.

If you need a more complex asset, I'd recommend loading an image and then passing that in to slider.setStyle.

Comment: Thing is yes and no! Line 2-5 must start with `track.graphics` then I get 100% black Slidertrack however the size is scaled automatically so the new track has exactly the same size as the default one. As I mentioned before in the graphical editor there are some dashed lines which mark the Region that gets skaled when skaling but I did not find the right actionscript command to do such a thing!

Comment: I've updated the code to include an example of how to set the "scale 9" region, those dashed lines you see in the Flash IDE. Also thanks for catching the missing .graphics calls, I've added those in too.